# Read USB data and display in browser

Tags: browser, cross-browser, usb, usbserial

We have a USB scale that sends very simple binary data for the weight of whatever is on it.

We want to auto-populate this data on a web form. Some work will be required on translating the bytes into a decimal number.

What programming language would be the easiest to implement this with? We will want a client based solution that is compatible with many browsers preferably.

We are pretty flexible with technology to use. I was thinking a java applet might be simplest? Anyone tried something like that before?

Thanks,
Gareth

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access low-level APIs via a browser, you should implement a BHO or ActiveX which will run in browser context and could have low level access to windows APIs like USB devices.

Overally you'll need browser extension, but implementation and method of use depends on you.

I suggest you to use ActiveX, but don't forget it just runs in IE. You can create a windows application which could communicate with Firefox extension, chrome extension or even a IE extension (BHO or ActiveX)

You can choose, if you want more details, you can ask here.

Comment: We would prefer something that is non-browser specific... if the choice came down to a certain browser the preference would be Firefox, Chrome then IE (in that order). Is ActiveX or XPCom (eg. firefox extension) the only way to do this?

Comment: Only way of connecting windows DLL and windows core stuff to browser context, yes.